# Joomla error Restricted access

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-template

I have a site in joomla.
I am getting an error 'Restricted access' while i tried to access my site .
It seems that the default template is not working and the access is going to the index.php file at outside.  The admin panel is working fine and the required template is changed to default one . And the permission of the template folders are 755 and the file permission is 655.
If any one can help me to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Go into admin,extensions->plugin manager.  Look for System - Legacy plugin.  It might be on the second page of plugins. Enable that. I had the exact same problem and that is how I remedied it.